# Conv1D as dimensionality reduction for LSTM

Tags: conv-neural-network, lstm, dimensionality-reduction

I was hoping to use CNN as a dimensionality reduction for my LSTM layers.

I have a panel dataset as the following:

```
sequence of days = 5065
lags = 14 days (those are time series lags)
features = 2767
```

Thus, `[5065, 14, 2767]`

As you can see I have more than half as many features as data points, and I wanted to reduce that. Ideally, I wanted to feed my LSTM layers with compressed feature information with something like 32 features, hopefully in the following shape:

```
[5065, 14, 32]
```

However, when setting up the CNN, I understand that filters should be 32, but what about my kernel size? I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At CNN, it is common to do dimensionality reduction  with a kernel size of `1x1`. Thereby only the filter/feature map dimension is affected and the spatial information is kept intact, because the input is 1:1 mapped to the output.

Hereby a good example is the [Inception](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4842.pdf) architecture, which uses 1x1 convolutions to reduce the dimensionality in the inception modules.

Comment: Oh, I see! So basically setting kernel = 1, I would have a convolutional reduction? That's very simple!

Comment: @asbrnn exactly. I would appreciate if you would mark my answer as correct. Just click the Check Icon beside my answer. Thanks!